# I could not find what is mistake in following code?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.3

Scenario:
I  have following case class:

```
case class Student(firstName:String, lastName: String)
```

I need to write reads and writes for Student. The json I provide is Sequence of Student.
For Example:

```
{
  "College": "Abc",
  "student" : [{"firstName" : "Jack", "lastName":"Starc"}, 
               {"firstName" : "Nicolas", "lastName":"Pooran"}
             ]
}
```

I have written my reads and writes as:

```
implicit val studentFormat = Json.format[Student]
implicit val studentRead = Json.reads[Student]
implicit val  studentWrite = Json.writes[Student]
implicit val studentReadSeq = Reads.seq(studentRead)
implicit val studentWriteSeq = Writes.seq(studentWrite)
```

Now I have to make a type parser and check whether the student is array or simple object. Here key i.e. Student can be Students or StudentInfo. So I have to make a parser on the basis of value provided in json.

For this I have done as following:

```
def studentCheck(jsonValue:  JsObject) = {
  var modifiedJson = Json.obj()
  for ((key, value) <- jsonValue.value) {
    if(value.validate[Student].isSuccess ) {
      val json = 
        studentFormat.writes(value.validate[Student].get).as[JsObject] 
      modifiedJson.+(key, json)
    }
    else if(studentReadSeq.reads(value).isSuccess) {
      //My Code will be here
      modifiedJson
    }
    else {
      println("Error")
      modifiedJson.+(key,value)
    }
  }
}

val studentJson = Json.obj(
  "college" -> "ABC",
  "student" -> Json.arr(
    Json.obj("firstName" -> "Jack", "lastName" -> "Starc"),
    Json.obj("firstName" -> "Nicolas", "entity" -> "Pooran")
  )
)

studentCheck(studentJson)
```

The problem I get here is, even provided List of Students the first case i.e. if statement is executed instead of elseif. How can I validate so it satisfy all the condition, i.e if Student object is provided if statement is executed and if List of Student is provided elseif statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a much better, safer, and functional way to validate a json.

Let's assume you have a `College` case class:

`case class College(college: String, students: List[Student])`

You can have a reader such as this:

```
object College{
   implicit val collegeReads = Reads[College] = (
     (JsPath \ "college").read[String] and
     (JsPath \ "students").read[List[Student]
   ) (College.apply _)
}
```

Then in order to validate it, you can do:

```
def foo(jsonValue:  JsObject)={
   jsonValue.validate[College].fold(
      errors =>  ,//handle parsing errors
      collage => //your code when the parsing is successfull.
   )
}
```